# Android x86 won't boot with GRUB 2 - stuck at Detecting Android x86

Tags: boot, bootloader, 7.1-nougat, android-x86

I recently installed Android x86, using ~~99 GB free space on an old drive, partitioning it into /dev/sdb3.

After reinstalling grub (accidentally selected "yes install grub" in the installation menu), Android x86 refused to boot. It just gets stuck at "Detecting Android x86"

Debug mode mentioned two errors:

"VFS: could not find a valid V7 on sdb3"

and

"EXT3-fs (loop0): error: couldn't mount because of unsupported optional features".

How do I fix these? It works fine with the version of grub that the installer provides.

Comment: Your error message is discussed here:   
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-7259024.html, it's for Gentoo, but maybe it could help you.

Comment: Why "accidentally"? You need to have its bootloader to be able to boot it, unless you create manually the boot files yourself. Note that installing its bootloader will erase your current bootloader, so if you had a previous OS already installed, you need to re-add it to the new bootloader files.

Comment: The message where you are stuck at "detecting Android-x86" has nothing to do with the fact that it installed the boot loader, but could be related to error in the bootloader config files.